# How to prepend outputs files with webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, eslint

I am working with webpack to build librairies into a saleforce dx project.

But I have an eslint validation when I push on github.

This validation fail because it try to check the validity of the webpack outputs.

I am trying to prepend the outputs files with `/* eslint-disable */` to disable eslint when I push.

So I try:

```
rules: [
      {
        loader: '@shoutem/webpack-prepend-append',
        query: {
          prepend: '/* eslint-disable */'
        }
      }
    ]
```

But the comment is not showing at the top of the output file. I think it prepends the input file.

How to prepend the **outputs** files with webpack ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file eslintdisable.sh

```
echo "/* eslint-disable */" | cat - dist/webpackoutput.js > /tmp/out && mv /tmp/out dist/webpackoutput.js
```

In above code replace `dist/webpackoutput.js` to the correct path where webpack output file is generated.

Then in package.json run webpack as follows

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode=production && sh ./eslintdisable.sh" }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `BannerPlugin` plugin to add a banner to the top of each generated chunk:

https://webpack.js.org/plugins/banner-plugin/

For example, you could use the following:

```
new webpack.BannerPlugin({
  banner: '/* eslint-disable */'
  raw: true
});
``
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's add an `!` into the comment and eslint is not disabled.

Comment: Looks like you need the `raw` option then

Comment: Yes, but webpack v 4.40 remove comments like `/* some text */`. So when I use raw option it's add comments but with multiple `*` into the comment like : `/** * eslint-disable */`

Answer (score 0):

I don't found any way to put a valid eslint comments in my webpack configuration.

So I use a nodejs script

```js
// nodeScript.js
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');

var pathDefault = '{build path}';
var jsFilesName = ['build1.js', 'build2.js'];

jsFilesName.forEach(function(file) {
  try {
    var contents = fs.readFileSync(
      path.join(__dirname, pathDefault, file + '.js'),
      'utf8'
    ); // copy contents file into a variable
    fs.writeFileSync(
      path.join(__dirname, pathDefault, file + '.js'),
      '/* eslint-disable */\r\n' + contents
    ); // rewrite content file with the concatenation of comments and contents
    console.log('   - ' + file + ' => Done');
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('   - ' + file + ' => KO');
    if (err) throw err;
  }
});
```

And you can start this script after the yarn/npm build

e.g.

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "yarn build && node ./nodeScript.js",
  }
}
```